# Cypress run performance tanked after upgrading to Apple Silicon

Tags: migration, cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

I upgraded from an older intel Macbook to my current M1 macbook. I expected some issues when moving to Apple Silicon, but I got most of them ironed out. I'll include this info in case the devil is in the details.

1. Migration from Macbook(intel) to the new macbook (apple silicon) caused existing packages and installs to not work. Resolved by nuking from orbit, installing fresh on ARM infra.
2. Homebrew installed, but not found. *Resolved by updating $PATH*
3. Yarn installed, which is how we manage dependencies in the repo
4. Cloned the repo
5. yarn installed cypress and all dependencies
6. Ran cypress, failed with generic error message. *Resolved by installing Rosetta 2*
7. Ran cypress, succeeded in opening the Cypress UI

From here forward, running any test results in dreadfully slow loading of the site I need to test. I'm seeing a trickle of 200 responses come in from very few network requests. Normally I'd see all of them in 2-3 seconds, but I'm timing out before any of the site's UI loads.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
The issue was that in our master branch, Cypress was running at `Cypress@9.5.4`

Apple Silicon can't handle Cypress versions older than `10.x.x`

Solution is to upgrade Cypress to latest version.